# How to control keyboard and widgets above it in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

My question is how to control the widgets when the keyboard slides up and slides back down.
I want the input fields to be in field of vision of the user.
As visible in the images down below, when I open the keyboard, the Container slides up and the Input field is not visible to the user.
What is happening:
[image: Keyboard closed]
[image: Keyboard opened and all items shifted upwards]

What I want to achieve:
[image: This is how I want it to behave]

Here is the code:

```
class SetupAccountScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BaseWidget(
      mainTitle: "Setup Account",
      description:
          "One last step to an awesome shopping experience, we’d like to know you more",
      content: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
//           Widgets for the textfield and button
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class BaseWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String mainTitle;
  final String description;
  final Widget content;

  BaseWidget({this.mainTitle, this.description, this.content});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Back",
          style: GoogleFonts.playfairDisplay(fontSize: 15),
        ),
        leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.chevron_left,
              size: 40,
            ),
            onPressed: () {}),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius:
                        BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(100))),
                child: content),
          ),
          Positioned.fill(
              child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 20),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(mainTitle,
                            style: GoogleFonts.playfairDisplay(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                fontSize: 25)),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          child: Text(description,
                              style: GoogleFonts.playfairDisplay(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                  fontSize: 15)),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` in your scaffold to false

```
  child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
```

Comment: This perfectly worked for this screen, but in some other screen items are getting behind the keyboard, is there some way to control the items?

Comment: yes , actually is not good user experience to make the user goes for the input , the input should go for him ..
so what you need to do just make your page scrollable , and **not to** make `resizeToAvoidBottomInset ` false to it can scroll to the needed position.

Answer (score 0):

Ok For this You Can Simply Use. `StatefulBuilder` in your ModalSheet.

Here is One Example :

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState /*You can rename this!*/) {
        return Container(
          height: heightOfModalBottomSheet,
          child: RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              heightOfModalBottomSheet += 10;
            });
          }),
        );
      });
});
```